# Best way to store and retrieve large arrays (or vectors) in Rust?

Tags: arrays, optimization, rust

Is there a fast and efficient way in Rust to store and retrieve arrays from the file system? I believe the bottleneck in my code is the iteration part. Is there any way to make that faster? Here's part of the code:

```
match File::open("LOOKUP_CACHE.dat") {
    Ok(val) => {
        // Since it exists, just load it into mem.
        let mut s = String::new();
        let mut a = val;
        println!("COMMENT: Found a Lookup Cache, loading it..");
        a.read_to_string(&mut s);
        for (index, value) in s.split(",").enumerate() {
            unsafe {
                build::WON_TABLE[index as usize] = u8::from_str_radix(value,10).ok().unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For context:

```
pub static mut WON_TABLE: &'static mut [u8] = &mut [0; 1000];
```

Comment: *I believe the bottleneck [...]* — don't do that. **Measure and know**. We could certainly post answers that we "believe" are faster; do you think those would be useful?

Comment: I'm just a beginner, heck I don't even know how to benchmark rust code. I would appreciate anything, but I think I found an answer.

Comment: Did you compile [in release mode](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/getting-started.html#building-for-release)? What is "too slow"? Did you read [*The Rust Programming Language* chapter on benchmarking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/benchmark-tests.html)?